# downgrade internet explorer while retaining settings

Tags: internet-explorer

I need to downgrade IE 11 to IE 10 for someone. This is simple enough. However, there are many settings that the person needs to keep so that can retain access to their remote desktop at work. They do not have the documentation that I originally implemented to use IE as a portal to their remote desktop. Their workplace's IT has also disbanded, leaving them in a bind.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Windows 7 or Windows 8.1?

Comment: They are using Windows 7.

Comment: The first step is to take notes of the settings require to access the remote desktop then all you should have to do is uninstall IE11.  There is no guarantee the settings will be saved and I know of no method that would provide that guarantee.